# replace double semicolo

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I could not replace double semicolon into 2's double quote.

```
result = original_text.replace(";;", ';"";');
result = result.replace(";;", ';"";');
```

What is the correct code?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
var a:String = "the;;quick;;brown;;fox";
trace(a.replace(/;;/g,'""')); //Use Regular Expression

result : the""quick""brown""fox
```